# Why does pnpm seem to detect an extra workspace?

Tags: pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I have set up a new project with `pnpm` and I'm unsure about some of the output I'm seeing when I run recursive commands. Specifically, it seems like `pnpm` is detecting 3 workspaces when I expect there should only be 2.

The project structure looks like this:

```
| workbooks/
|-- workbook-one/
|---- package.json
|-- workbook-two/
|---- package.json
|
| package.json
| pnpm-workspace.yaml
```

The `pnpm-workspace.yaml` file is:

```
packages:
  - "workbooks/*"
```

I have a build command in the top-level `package.json` like so:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "project:deploy": "pnpm -r --if-present --workspace-concurrency=1 project:deploy"
  }
  ...
}
```

Each of the two workspaces has a `project:deploy` script. However, when I run `pnpm project:deploy` I see this in the output:

```
> pnpm -r --if-present --workspace-concurrency=1 project:deploy

Scope: 2 of 3 workspace projects
```

Why is the scope "2 of 3", rather than "2 of 2"?

Answer (score 1):

usually the root directory is also included if is has package.json file. you can use `pnpm list -r --depth=-1` command to list all workspaces to find out what is the extra workspace you are not expecting